# Knockout compute format number and compute property by list object has parse json to array and add dynamic

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I use Knockout to create grid dynamic custom:

---

My HTML:

```
<fieldset id="DSThanhVienDuHopviewModel">
      <legend class="title_fieldset">
Danh sách thành viên dự họp
       </legend>
     <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0"  >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="headRow headColumn" >STT</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn">Chức vụ</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn">Họ Tên</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn">Vốn góp</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn">Tỷ lệ(%)</th>

            <th class="headRow headColumn" colspan="2"> Chọn </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: bbhops' >
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="rowItemSmall"><label data-bind='text: $index() + 1'></label> </td>
            <td class="rowItemNormal">
            <input type="text" class="editorCombobox"  data-bind='value: MaChucDanh, attr: { name: "ListofBienBanHop[" + $index() + "].MaChucDanh", id: "ThemThanhVien_" + $index() }' />
            </td>


            <td class="rowItemLarge"> <input type="text" class="editorTable"   data-bind='value: HoTenTV, attr: { name: "ListofBienBanHop[" + $index() + "].HoTenTV" }' />

            </td>

            <td class="rowItem"> <input type="text" class="editorTable"   data-bind="value: VonGop, attr: { name: 'ListofBienBanHop[' + $index() + '].VonGop' }" />



            </td>
            <td class="rowItemMedium"> 
                <label data-bind='value: TyLe, attr: { name: "ListofBienBanHop[" + $index() + "].TyLe" }' />

            </td>
            <td class="rowItemSmall"><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removebbhop'>Xóa</a></td>
            <td class="rowItemSmall"><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addbbhop'>Thêm</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

      </fieldset>
```

---

My Script:

```
var BBHopModel = function (bbhops) {
    var self = this;
    self.bbhops = ko.observableArray(bbhops);
 self.isEqualsTongVon = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.bbhops().length; i++)
            total += parseInt( self.bbhops()[i].VonGop);
        var TongVon = parseInt($('#VonVND').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
        return (TongVon == total);

    });
    self.addbbhop = function () {
        self.bbhops.push({
            HoTenTV: "",
            MaChucDanh: ""
            ,TyLe: 0
            , VonGop: 0
            , SoBNhan: ""
        });

    };

    self.removebbhop = function (bbhop) {
        if (self.bbhops().length > 1) {
            self.bbhops.remove(bbhop);
        }
        else {
            alert("Bắt buộc phải có 1 thành viên trong biên bản họp ");
        }
    };



};
var bbhopviewModel = new BBHopModel([{"TongVon":0,"HoTenTV":null,"ID":0,"MaChucDanh":null,"SoBNhan":null,"TyLe":0,"VonGop":0}]);
ko.applyBindings(bbhopviewModel, document.getElementById("DSThanhVienDuHopviewModel"));
```

In my project it works but in jsfiddle not work :  http://jsfiddle.net/htangiau/84mjovx6/

I want  column VonGop format number same as 3,000,000.123 and column TyLe format as 5%,
when changed column VonGop text, Column Tyle = VonGop/TongVon * 100.

Thanks!!!

---

Giau

Comment: What is TongVon? You don't have it anywhere in code.. Confusing.. same with `$('#VonVND').val()`

Comment: you can set any value to test or add input id = VonVND, Thanks

Comment: you can set any value to test or add input id = VonVND, I set json data by @Html.Raw, i want to compute column Tyle when column VonGop change value: Tyle = VonGop/TongVon * 100